# AngularJS - ng-bind - binding a url

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind a var which contains an URL and ng-click.

I'm binding this url - but it doesn't show as a hyperlink.

var myURL = "http://www.cnn.com');'>LINK"

it appears literally ...  like

```
<a ng-click='formatter.GotoLink('http://www.cnn.com');'>LINK</a>
```

instead of just "**LINK**"

Any ideas what's wrong with myURL string?

```
formatter.GotoLink = function (url){
    window.open(link,'_system');
}
```

Comment: You have a `'` quote mismatch. Use `"` as outer quotes for your HTML attributes

Answer (score 3):

First, wrap your expression between double quotes

```
<a ng-click="formatter.GotoLink('http://www.cnn.com');">LINK</a>
```

Then make sure your function uses the right param (`url` or `link`)

```
formatter.GotoLink = function (url){
    window.open(url,'_system');
}
```

Finally, for a link to show as an hyperlink, you need an **href**.
You could do this (if you don't need the window object):

```
<a ng-href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_system">LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a ng-click="formatter.GotoLink('http://www.cnn.com')">LINK</a>
```

Comment: How do I build the string.

Comment: var arrOfDocs = [];                      arrOfDocs.push("<a ng-click="formatter.GotoLink('http://www.cnn.com');">LINK</a>");     this doesn't work

Comment: why are you using an array to build a string?

Comment: The links come from a JSON file - I need to build an array of hyperlinks that then can be displayed (binding) and clicked on

Comment: String website = "cnn.com";String link = "<a ng-click='formatter.GotoLink(Website)'>LINK</a>"; Push this link into your array

Comment: It shows as link now.. But nothing happens when I click it

Comment: Your function should be called. Not sure why it isn't